# Cell phone tracker for delivery services

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, gps, location-services

I'm working on an app that needs to get the real-time location of a specific phone number, which belongs to my company. Right now, I'm using the phonenumbers library to parse the phone number and the geocoding API to get the location associated with it.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder

phone_number1 = phonenumbers.parse("+5599999999999")

print("\nPhone Numbers Location\n")
p0rint(geocoder.description_for_number(phone_number1, "en"))
```

My question is: would it be possible to request the location of a specific phone number that belongs to my company? I would like to receive the real-time latitude and longitude associated with that number.

Could only the seeker do something like this?

I appreciate any help.

My question is: would it be possible to request the location of a specific phone number that belongs to my company? I would like to receive the real-time latitude and longitude associated with that number.

Would only the seeker give me this answer?

Comment: You are using a phone number library to map a phone number to a geographic region. This is based on country code and area code.  It tells you nothing of the physical location of the device. You will need to use a location services/gps library to obtain the device location and have it report in